# pyspark derive multiple columns

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe where there are 3 columns: update_ts, text, pred_label. But, the "pred_label" column is in a weird format: json string I believe.

here is an eg:

```
Row(update_ts='2021-07-22T00:26:49Z', text='The best car ever!', pred_label='[{score=0.998854398727417, label=POSITIVE}]')
```

I am looking to create another dataframe where I have pred_label col split up into two separate columns : score and label. So, final output df will have 4 cols : update_ts, text, label, score.

I am able to do the above in pure Python easily:

```
def split_col(row):
    label = row[0]['label']
    score = row[0]['score']
    return pd.Series([label, score], index=['label', 'score'])

def split_labels_scores(df):
    df[['label', 'score']] = df['pred_label'].apply(split_col)
    df.drop(columns=['pred_label'], inplace=True)
    return df

final_df = split_labels_scores(df)
```

But, in PySpark (databricks), I do not know how to do it. Any help is appreciated. I am trying out withColumn, udfs, StructType etc.

Update: I think the original df has a StringDataType() because I did it that way when I declared an udf.

```
my_udf = F.udf(my_fn, StringType())
df = df.withColumn('pred_label', my_udf(F.col("description")))
```

Perhaps, if I could change the udf to return a List instead of a StringType, then, things might be easier downstream.

Answer (score 1):

Easier way would be using **`regexp_extract()`** as this is not a json formatted string.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
rd = [Row(update_ts='2021-07-22T00:26:49Z', text='The best car ever!', pred_label='[{score=0.998854398727417, label=POSITIVE}]')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(rd).\
withColumn("score", regexp_extract(col("pred_label"), "score=(.+),",1)).\
withColumn("label", regexp_extract(col("pred_label"), "label=(.+)}",1)).\
drop("pred_label")
df.show(10,False)
#+--------------------+------------------+-----------------+--------+
#|update_ts           |text              |score            |label   |
#+--------------------+------------------+-----------------+--------+
#|2021-07-22T00:26:49Z|The best car ever!|0.998854398727417|POSITIVE|
#+--------------------+------------------+-----------------+--------+
```

---

If you are able to convert `[{score=0.998854398727417, label=POSITIVE}]` to a valid json string then we can use `from_json + explode + unnest` to get the score,label dynamically.

Comment: Thanks @notNull. In your solution, what is rd? It looks like a some sort of list..I am not sure. I have a sparkDataframe where one of its columns needs to be split. It looks like you are taking one Row....and splitting it. Can you please show me how to do similar split for an entire df?

Comment: @user1717931, rd is an `Row` and I'm creating sample dataframe from `rd`. If you already have dataframe then the same code works as is.. `withColumn("score", regexp_extract(col("pred_label"), "score=(.+),",1)).\` just change `column_name` in `col("<your column name>")`